# Why create java extension classes when you can just create classes as part of java program?

Tags: java

I was reading about class loaders in java, came across Extension class loaders. As per my understanding these extension classes are like JRE classes. They will be available to multiple java programs using the that particular JRE, Apart from that does it have any other advantages compared to custom java classes that we create as part of java programs? What if I have only one Java program using my JRE, Is there any use case for creating extension classes?

Comment: I've not yet found *any* real beneficial use of the [extension mechanism](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ext/index.html) in all my years. It's occasionally been abused to load JDBC drivers without having to tweak the classpath, but that's not a good idea either. Since it affects *every* JVM started from a given Java installation, using it seems risky at best. Note that there's no specific "extension classes" (a term that seems to be used in the C# world), it's just a mechanism to load (normal) classes from a specific place.

Comment: It's a feature primary used by computer system designers. Amazon for example uses it, for shipping their custom JRE/JDK [Amazon Corretto](https://aws.amazon.com/corretto/?nc1=h_ls&filtered-posts.sort-by=item.additionalFields.createdDate&filtered-posts.sort-order=desc)

Comment: I think at one time, there were some libraries that made use of the extension classloader, but now [extensions are no longer supported](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/jar/Attributes.Name.html#EXTENSION_LIST).  No one should use them.